# Bracketed Paste Mode in Terminal.app?

Tags: terminal

Does Terminal.app support "bracketed paste mode"?  This mode inserts an escape sequence when pasting so that (e.g.) editors can handle pasted text differently from typed text.

http://www.xfree86.org/current/ctlseqs.html#Bracketed%20Paste%20Mode

Comment: Interesting question, I didn't even know such a thing existed. A quick Internet search has returned this article: https://cirw.in/blog/bracketed-paste, which states that `Readline (as of v 7) and thus Bash (as of v4.4) now have support for bracketed paste mode too! You can enable it by adding set enable-bracketed-paste on to your ~/.inputrc.`. Unfortunately, macOS is stuck with Bash 3.2.x, and that option is not supported.

Comment: You  might be able to get this functionality with iTerm2 (https://www.iterm2.com/)

Comment: See my Stack Overflow answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7053522/754997

Comment: Note that Zsh and Vim (as of version 8) both enable Bracketed Paste Mode by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it absolutely does.  This is the result of pasting THING into vim open in my terminal:

[image]

The `[200~`  marks are the result of the paste mode.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Terminal.app in Mac OS X does support "bracketed paste mode" by default, now that zsh is the default shell.

The pasted item is reverse-highlighted [screenshot].

[image: visual appearance of paste in zsh with bracketed paste enabled.]

And to disable bracketed paste in zsh, from the command line:

```
unset zle_bracketed_paste
```

Comment: How does this answer differ from the one already provided?  Both are the same answer.