# Copying and pasting between terminal windows adds extra characters

Tags: terminal, command-line, copy-paste

I've recently moved from MacOS 10.4 to 10.15.  I use Japanese/English/Russian/Chinese, and I've noticed a different behavior when copying between terminal windows on 10.15. Extra characters, specifically 00~, 01~ are prepended and appended to my buffer.  As an example,

```
ideas/2020
```

becomes

```
00~ideas/202001~
```

when pasted.
I'm unsure if this issue is a function of the languages or a significant change in behavior in the terminals, but it's rather bothersome.

Any suggestions on what might inhibit the addition of extra characters in the buffer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a result of bracketed paste mode, in which the Terminal sends "bracket" escape sequences to mark pasted content. If the thing it's being pasted into understands this, it's great; if the thing being pasted into *doesn't*... you get what you're seeing. You might find help from [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334247/bracketed-paste-mode-in-terminal-app), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212099/how-do-i-disable-the-weird-characters-from-bracketed-paste-mode-on-the-mac-os), or [this blog post from Conrad Irwin](https://cirw.in/blog/bracketed-paste).

Comment: @GordonDavisson That's the answer.  Sadly, didn't know what it was called or I would  have found it in the search. :/